# ExecutorService working fine with submit but throwing error for invokeAll

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

My code is working with submit() of callable to ExecutorService. But when I tried to change it to invokeAll(), I am getting compilation error.

code:

```
public class FutureDemo{
    public FutureDemo(){
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        /*
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i);
            Future<Long> futureResult = service.submit(myCallable);
            Long result = null;
            try{
                result = futureResult.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }catch(TimeoutException e){
                System.out.println("Time out after 5 seconds");
                futureResult.cancel(true);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println("Error: Interrupted");
            }catch(ExecutionException ee){
                System.out.println("Error: Execution interrupted");
            }
            System.out.println("Result:"+result);
        }
        */
        List<MyCallable> futureList = new ArrayList<MyCallable>();
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i);
            futureList.add(myCallable);
        }
        try{
            Future<Long> futures = service.invokeAll(futureList);  // error
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FutureDemo fc = new FutureDemo();
    }
    class MyCallable implements Callable{
        Long id = 0L;
        public MyCallable(Long val){
            this.id = val;
        }
        public Long call(){
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FutureDemo.java:31: error: no suitable method found for invokeAll(List<FutureDemo.MyCallable>)
                        Future<Long> futures = service.invokeAll(futureList);  // error
                                                  ^
method ExecutorService.<T#1>invokeAll(Collection<? extends 

Callable<T#1>>,long,TimeUnit) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ExecutorService.<T#2>invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T#2>>) is not applicable
      (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#2 exist so that argument type List<FutureDemo.MyCallable> conforms to formal parameter type Collection<? extends Callable<T#2>>)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T#1>>,long,TimeUnit)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T#2>>)
```

Comment: MyCallable implements Callable<Long>

Comment: Submit is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) returns a `List<Future<T>>`, but you're trying to assign the result to a variable of type `Future<T>`.

Two, you're passing a `List<MyCallable>` as an argument, where a `MyCallable` is a raw `Callable`. Being raw, generics are erased and the compiler cannot infer an appropriate type that would match the expected `Collection<? extends Callable<T>>` parameter type.

Don't use raw types. Read

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Then appropriately change your class declaration to

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<Long> {
```

Comment: Got it :). It's working fine now.  is invokeAll() from ExecutorService &  CountdownLatch with countDown are nearly same?.

Comment: @ravindra _nearly same_ in what regards? No, I wouldn't say a `CountdownLatch` and an `ExecutorService` are the same at all.

Comment: same in the sense : does they provide same result of?  waiting for completion of all tasks  in invokeAll &  completion of task after countDown becoming Zero.

Comment: re-phrasing: I have to wait for completion of 10 tasks in a batch. is invokeAll() and await() with countdown() produce same result?

Comment: @ravindra Kind of for the behavior, sure.